# How to Retrieve Values from a Class Within a Class Using JavaScript

Tags: html

I am not experienced with `HTML` and 'JavaScript', and is having a roadblock when attempting to check the values from a `class`.

Below is the source as seen from `F12`

[image]

I would like to retrieve all `createdby text -muted` values (as they may contain more than one row) to check if any of them matches `SYSTEM`, may I know how can it be done?

I understand that an image is not the best way to portrait my question, I will try to type the source in my question.

My apologies, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `NodeList` which contains `createdby text-muted` classes using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) as follows.

```
const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".createdby .text-muted");
elems.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.innerHTML);  // This will contain the text value of the selected selector
});
```